# How to sum tree elements using folds?

Tags: haskell, tree, higher-order-functions, fold

I'm trying to learn the 'folds' (only 'foldr' and 'foldl') functionality of Haskell through doing some sample coding. I have defined a Tree (not binary) like so:

```
data NTree a = Nil | Tree a [NTree a] deriving Show
```

I want to sum all the elements of the tree using a function. I have outlined the type signature and the base case of the function, but I'm not sure how to implement the logic itself using folds. This is what I have so far:

```
sumElements :: NTree Int -> Int
sumElements Nil = 0
sumElements tree = foldr (???) 0 tree
```

I really can't think of how to get started. Any help filling in the folds function would be appreciated.

Comment: I'd start by pattern matching against the constructor in the second equation: `sumElements (Tree x children) = ...`.

Comment: I mean, you should either pattern match, or use foldr, not both.

Comment: @LouisWasserman I want to try to do this using foldr, but I'm not sure how to get started. I don't get the logic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pretty much have it.

```
sumElements tree = foldr (+) 0 tree
```

Comment: Thank you! I was overthinking it. I guess my only question is- is this implementation going to iterate all the nodes (specifically with my implementation of a non binary tree)?

Comment: Sure.  `foldr` should go through the entire data structure, after all.

Comment: That assumes `NTree` has a `Foldable` instance.

Comment: Yes, it does.  That seems strongly implied by the original question.

Comment: The OP's comment above is what made me think otherwise.

Comment: I have been getting this error when trying to use the function in the answer: `• No instance for (Foldable NTree) arising from a use of ‘foldr’
`

Comment: That's because you need to implement the `Foldable` type class for `NTree`, which is the only way you can use `foldr` on an `NTree`.  I recommend writing it yourself than automatically deriving it, perhaps by looking at [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/haskell/example/2556/an-instance-of-foldable-for-a-binary-tree).

Answer (score 1):

In order to apply foldr to your tree, you should define an instance of Foldable for your Tree.
In short, you have to supply an implementation the 2 functions required for a data type to be "foldable" : foldMap and foldr.

You can learn more in [this tutorial](https://riptutorial.com/haskell/example/2556/an-instance-of-foldable-for-a-binary-tree).

(Im also a begginer, I hope this will help you and others)

Comment: Foldable only requires one of `foldMap` or `foldr` to be defined. It is not necessary to implement both, but you can do that to improve performance in certain cases.